# how to fetch data according id/slug in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

what i am trying to do is fetching the data according to category id/slug. for e.g i have two categories(brown, black) as you can see below. how to fetch blog_set data according to category id/slug ?

i am probably new to ReactJs. it would be great if anyone could help me out what i am trying to do is. thank you so much in advance.

endpoint-url : http://localhost:8000/api/category

api-data:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "brown",
        "slug": "brown",
        "image": "http://localhost:8000/media/category/bg_1.jpg",
        "description": "",
        "created_on": "2020-05-08T15:21:02Z",
        "status": true,
        "blog_set": [
            {
                "id": 6,
                "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/blog_detail/test3",
                "title": "test3",
                "slug": "test3",
                "image": "http://localhost:8000/media/blog/author.jpg",
                "description": "test3",
                "created_on": "2020-05-13T13:36:45Z",
                "status": true,
                "category": [
                    1
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "black",
        "slug": "black",
        "image": "http://localhost:8000/media/category/image_7.jpg",
        "description": "",
        "created_on": "2020-05-08T17:14:43Z",
        "status": true,
        "blog_set": [
            {
                "id": 10,
                "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/blog_detail/test3",
                "title": "Hamid",
                "slug": "test3",
                "image": "http://localhost:8000/media/blog/person_2_2beHkt1.jpg",
                "description": "test",
                "created_on": "2020-05-13T14:59:30.855849Z",
                "status": true,
                "category": [
                    2
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

./src/Category.js

```
export default class App extends Component{
 state = {
    bloglist: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/category");
      const jsonResponse = await response.json();
      this.setState({ bloglist: jsonResponse });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  render(){
        {
    const { bloglist } = this.state;
    if (!bloglist) {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>loading...</h1>
        </div>
      );
    }

    return(
        <div>
        <h1>Category</h1>
        {bloglist.map((bloglist) => (
            <div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="blog-entry animate d-md-flex">

                        <img src={bloglist.image} className="App-logo"/>

                          <h3 class="mb-2">{bloglist.title}</h3>
                          <h3 class="mb-2">{bloglist.blog_set.title}</h3>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            ))}
        </div>

        );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How does this whole thing work? How do you determine which `id`/`slug` do you need?

Comment: How does the backend Accept the parameter to filter based on `id/slug`?

Comment: according to the category id/slug, i want to fetch blog_set data. as you can see above api-data. @MD.TabishMahfuz

Comment: Yes that is the data being returned from the API but can you send a parameter to the API for the `id` or  `slug`?

Comment: @MD.TabishMahfuz  hey there.... please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62701259/how-to-use-search-effect-in-reactjs    . Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if the api supports fetching single category with id/slug. Then if you can call API with the id/slug from added to the fetch API call. If you want to show a separate page with the selected category you can enable a route with URL parameter with react-router-dom (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params). And with this you will get the id/slug in the match prop which will be the `this.props.history.match` or with `useParams()` hooks. and then you can use it to call API with the selected id/slug.

Your UI URL will look like this. `http://localhost:3000/category/:id` and on browser it will look like this `http://localhost:3000/category/black` so when you call `useParams()` hook in your component it will be like `{id} = useParams()`;

Now you can use this `id` to call the single selection API which might look like this `<api_url>:<port>/category/black` or `<api_url>:<port>/category?slug=black`

Comment: hey there.... please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62701259/how-to-use-search-effect-in-reactjs    .  Hopefully you can help me here. Thanxx!!

Comment: i'm sorry.... i deleted that... please take a look at this link--> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62792040/how-to-login-in-reactjs

Comment: i'm sorry.... i deleted that... please take a look at this link--> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62792040/how-to-login-in-reactjs

Answer (score 0):

Pass query-params access deep properties
GET http://localhost:8000/api/category?slug=`value`

```
fetchData = async () => {
try {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/category?slug=value");
  const jsonResponse = await response.json();
  this.setState({ bloglist: jsonResponse });
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

};

Comment: and how to pass the value while fetching?

Comment: oh, I thought you are trying to fetch data on click, how do want to fetch the data, need little more explanation

Comment: hey there.... please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62701259/how-to-use-search-effect-in-reactjs    .  Hopefully you can help me here. Thanxx!!