# how to login in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how to login in ReactJS?

i am probably new to reactJS, so i have no idea about how to proper login in Reactjs. i tried something like below but that's not proper working.
it would be great if anybody could help me out for what i'm trying to do. thank you so much in advance.

login-api end point: http://localhost:8000/api/login

```
export default class App  extends Component{


  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            username: "",
            password: "",
        }
        this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this)
    }

    onFormSubmit(values){
      console.log(values);

      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("username", values.username);
      formData.append("password", values.password);

        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        };

      fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/login', options).then(() => {
        this.props.history.replace('/home')
        }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(this.props.state)
      })


    };


 render(){
    return(

    <div>

    <section class="login_part section_padding ">

                    <div class="login_part_form">

                            <Form onFinish={this.onFormSubmit}>
                                <div class="col-md-12 form-group p_star">
                                    <Form.Item name="username">
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required />
                                    </Form.Item>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12 form-group p_star">
                                  <Form.Item name="password">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control"
                                        placeholder="Password" required />
                                   </Form.Item>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                    <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn_3">
                                        log in
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </Form>


                        </div>
    </section>



    </div>

    )
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, looking at your code, i do not really see you changing your state anywhere.
Looks like you lack some simple handlers, that will use [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html) method to modify the password and username in your state. You want to probably do it onChange of an input.
After that in your onFormSubmit function you want to get the values from your state and send those to the server.

Comment: i am probably new to reactjs. it would be great if you can help me through remotely?

Comment: @bounty try writing a function that takes 2 parameters: event and name, after that using setState method set the ```[name]: event.target.value``` you can read more using the link above

Comment: i am learning react. i have no idea about this. it would be great if you can connect my laptop though remotely and it would be more great hopefully if you can solve it also. :)

Comment: i am learning react. i have no idea about this. it would be great if you can connect my laptop though remotely and it would be more great hopefully if you can solve it.

Comment: do you use teamviewer or anydesk for remote desktop?